# Simplify $\sqrt{-3}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I was reading about this known fallacy
$$
-1 = i^2 = i \cdot i = \sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{1} = 1
$$
and according to Wikipedia *"The fallacy is that the rule $\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{y} $  is generally valid only if both x and y are positive"*

So  my question is, how come we can say that $\sqrt{-3} = \sqrt{3}i$ ?. Aren't we applying the same mistake as the fallacy? Like $\sqrt{-3} = \sqrt{(-1)(3)} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3}i$ cannot be since -1 is negative.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "if *both* $x$ and $y$ are positive."  If $x=-1$ and $y=3$ then if is false that both are positive.

Comment: Note the key word **generally**. The identity may be valid in other cases (as in this one), but it gets more complicated when you allow for nonreal or even nonpositive $x$ and $y$.

Comment: check this link https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/imaginary-numbers.html

Answer (score 0):

First: the fact that the identity $\sqrt a\sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}$ is only valid for nonnegative reals $a,b{}$ does not mean that it is *always* false for other numbers.

But let's see the proof of the identity to see where it's essencial that $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative:

> $$(\sqrt a\sqrt b)^2=\left(\sqrt a\right)^2\left(\sqrt b\right)^2=ab$$
>   Therefore, $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$.

Now, let's do this for $a=b=-1$:

> $$(\sqrt {-1}\sqrt {-1})^2=\left(\sqrt {-1}\right)^2\left(\sqrt {-1}\right)^2=(-1)(-1)$$
>   Therefore, $\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt {-1}\sqrt {-1}$.

The problem arises in the conclusion. The definition of $\sqrt{\:}$ says:
$$\sqrt{x}=y\iff y^2=x\text{ and }y\ge 0$$

The last condition is essential. Many books for high school student say that $\sqrt 4$ has "two solutions" but this is totally wrong. What has two solutions is the equation $x^2=4$, but $\sqrt 4$ is $2$ and not, ever, $-2$.

In the fallacy we are saying in essence that $\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt {-1}\sqrt {-1}$, but this is wrong because $\sqrt {-1}\sqrt {-1}<0$.

Comment: I'm not native English speaker: should that word "ever" be "never"?

Comment: I think "ever" is fine as you put it.
I think that the key word of my question is that Wikipedia put the word "only" as in that identity should be used "only" when x and y are positives.

Comment: @VladimirLenin Where did they say that?

Comment: @ajotatxe Another issue that is important here is that while $\sqrt{4}=2$, the $\sqrt{-4} = \pm 2i$ depending on which side of the Riemann surface the point $-4$ lies.  For example, if the plane is cut along the negative real axis, and we are evaluating $\sqrt{-4}$ "infinitesimally" above the branch cut, then we have $\sqrt{-4}=2i$.